# React how to handle federated login redirects with private routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, aws-amplify

I'm using AWS Amplify for Authentication via email/pw & Google federated login. I'm also utilizing the `Hub` API to listen for authentication changes. When a user logs in with email/pw our user is redirected to a Private route & everything works as expected. When a user logs in with the Google federated login, the page redirects to google and then my private route catches this login and redirects it back to sign in.

After redirecting to google for login, Amplify is suppose to send us back to `/PrivateRoute`.

I tried adjusting my `<Route>` properties with `exact` and `strict` however the problem persists.

This is the standard way I've been handling private routes with authentication but my first time using Amplify federated logins. Any Suggestions?

See example code below:

**aws-exports.js**

```js
...
cont awsConfig = {
...
oauth: {
  ...
  redirectSignIn: "http://localhost:3000/PrivateRoute
  redirectSignOut: "http://localhost:3000/SignIn
  ...
}
```

**PrivateRoute.js**

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from "../AuthContextProvider.js";

const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
  const { component: Component, ...rest } = props;
  const user = useContext(AuthContext);
  console.log(user)
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(matchProps) =>
        user ? <Component {...matchProps} /> : <Redirect to="/SignIn" />
      }
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

**AuthContextProvider.js**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Amplify, { Auth, Hub } from "aws-amplify";

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    Amplify.configure(props.awsconfig);

    Hub.listen("auth", ({ payload: { event, data } }) => {
      switch (event) {
        case "signIn":
          setUser(data);
          break;
        case "signOut":
          setUser(null);
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    });

    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then((user) => setUser(user))
      .catch((user) => setUser(null));
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={user}>{props.children}</AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthContextProvider;
export { AuthContext };
```

**SignIn.js**

```js
...
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import { AuthContext } from "../AuthContextProvider.js";
...

const SignIn = ({ config }) => {
...
  const user = useContext(AuthContext);

  async function handleSignIn() {
    try {
      const user = await Auth.signIn(email, password);
      if (user) {
        history.push(redirectPath);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error signing in:", error);
    }
  }

  
  if (user) {
    return <Redirect to={redirectPath} />;
  }

  return (

    <Button onClick={() => handleSignIn()}
       Email/PW Log In
    </Button>
    <Button onClick={() => Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider: "Google" })}
       Google Log In
    </Button>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this solution is now obvious.

In my **AuthContextProvider.js** I needed to wait for my asynchronous authorization before loading my dependent components.

By adding the following state:

```
const [isLoadingUser, setIsLoadingUser] = useState(true);
```

I could then set that:

```
Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then((user) => {
        setUser(user)
        setIsLoadingUser(false) // set bool upon completion
      })
      .catch((user) => {
        setUser(null)
        setIsLoadingUser(false)  // set bool upon failure
      });
  }, []);
```

Then finally I can instead return a loading component if my whole app is to be behind authentication:

```
if (isLoadingUser) {
    return (<LoadingUser />)
}
```